# R plotly sankey nodes opacity

Tags: r, plotly

The default sankey chart has links that are grey and transparent so that you can see the overlapping links. I am trying add color to the links in the example Sankey chart below; is there a way to make the links partially transparent so I can see overlapping links?

```
p <- plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  orientation = "h",

  node = list(
    label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
    color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 20,
    line = list(
      color = "black",
      width = 0.5
    )
  ),

  link = list(
    source = c(0,1,0,2,3,3),
    target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
    value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2),
    color = c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow","blue", "red"),
    opacity = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
    alpha = 0.5
  )
) %>% 
  layout(
    title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
    font = list(
      size = 10
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. You can directly specify the opacity in the color as follows:

```
link = list(
    source = c(0,1,0,2,3,3),
    target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
    value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2),
    color = 'rgba(0,255,255,0.4)'
)
```

You can also put in an array:

```
color = c("rgba(0,0,255,0.4)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)")
```